# How to insert a name of list table into a column using R

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, reshape, reshape2

I have data like this:

```
# Data
varx1 <- data.frame(datex = c("2018/01/01","2018/01/02","2018/01/03"), x = c(101,102,103)) 
varx2 <- data.frame(datex = c("2018/01/01","2018/01/02","2018/01/03","2018/01/04","2018/01/05"), x = c(10,11,12,13,14))
varx3 <- data.frame(datex = c("2018/01/01"), x = c(1000))
combination <- list(`code status OK01` = varx1, `code trx OCS02` = varx2, `Revenue 101` = varx3)
combination
```

I want to have the result like this:

```
# Result
result <- data.frame(datex = c("2018/01/01","2018/01/02","2018/01/03","2018/01/01","2018/01/02","2018/01/03","2018/01/04","2018/01/05","2018/01/01"),
                 combination = c("code status OK01","code status OK01","code status OK01","code trx OCS02","code trx OCS02","code trx OCS02","code trx OCS02","code trx OCS02","Revenue 101"),
                 x = c(101,102,103,10,11,12,13,14,1000))
result
```

Need help for this problem. Thanks

Comment: What do you need exactly? Could you provide more detail?

Comment: Please read [ask]. Your question isn't clear at the moment.

Comment: Hi sir. would you run the script? i want to create a new column using name of dataframe within list. Thanks

Comment: What does `combination` contain in the first code chunk?

Comment: sorry for the code, i have updated, thanks before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the variable `varx3`, but that will work:

```
library(tidyverse)
result <- varx1 %>%
  mutate(combination="code status OK01") %>% 
  bind_rows(varx2 %>% 
              mutate(combination="code trx OCS02")) %>% 
  bind_rows(varx3 %>% 
              mutate(combination="Revenue 101")) %>% 
  select(datex, combination, x)
result
```

if you want to work in your list (given the list is static):

```
library(tidyverse)
result <- combination[[1]] %>% 
  mutate(combination="code status OK01") %>% 
  bind_rows(combination[[2]] %>% 
              mutate(combination="code trx OCS02")) %>% 
  bind_rows(combination[[3]] %>% 
              mutate(combination="Revenue 101")) %>% 
  select(datex, combination, x)
result
```

You pointed out, you have more than 100 variables. So if you have the `combination` dataframe with 100 variables, each in a single dataframe in a large list, you can use:

```
library(tidyverse)
var_names <- names(combination)
df <- NULL
for (i in 1:length(var_names)) {
  df[[i]] <- combination[[i]] %>%
    mutate(combinate=var_names[[i]])
}
result <- bind_rows(df)
result
```

Comment: hello.. my internet is low, so every time i edit it doesn't save it. but, can you make combination variable more general sir? because i have 100 items. Thanks

Comment: updated my answer

Comment: Thanks sir. It works